# How do I url-encode the value of request_uri in nginx?

Tags: angular, nginx, seo, rendertron

I have installed [rendertron](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/rendertron/blob/main/README.md#query-parameters) to help with SEO / server side rendering of my Angular website. Everything works fine until I use query parameters.

As you can see from the linked section of the FAQs above it requires for the full URI to be encoded, including the `?`, `&` and `=` characters in the query e.g. `https://mywebsite.com/render/http://mywebsite.com/%3Fpage%3Dhome`

I'm using nginx to detect the robots I wish to redirect to the prerendered page but parameters are  being passed through as normal. Is there a way to get nginx to replace the characters listed above with url encoded ones? Here is my redirect portion of the nginx config:

```
location /rendertron/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/render/$scheme://$host:$server_port$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: is this the answer you are looking for using js?

encodeURI()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI

If you are wanting to specifically replace characters you could do this one,
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll

Comment: @IsaacLyne Thanks for the reference, I have added my solution below which ended up needing the nginx js-module and some tweaking of the configs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I ended up adding the nginx js-module and creating this function:

```js
import qs from 'querystring';

function encodeParams(r) {
    return encodeURIComponent(qs.stringify(r.args));
}

export default { urlEncode }
```

I modified the nginx site configuration like this:

```
js_import conf.d/url_encode.js;

js_set $encoded_params url_encode.encodeParams;

server {

    # other config ...

        location /rendertron/ {

         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;

         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/render/$scheme://$host:$server_port$1%3F$encoded_params;
        }
```

I had to manually add `%3F` before adding the `encoded_params`. This seems to work fine for URIs with or without query parameters and solves my problem.